# Unexpected end of Subtree exception in Spring data query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hql

**Need to get all the package list if 'processList' variable is empty but it is throwing error**

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT pd FROM com.nividous.rpa.domain.PackageDeployment pd WHERE (IsEmpty(:processList) or pd.processName in (:processList) )")
 public Page<PackageDeployment> getActiveProcessList(@Param("processList") List<String> 
   processList,Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the parenthesis and you also may need to use IsEmpty like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT pd FROM PackageDeployment pd WHERE IsEmpty(:processList) or pd.processName in (:processList)")
public Page<PackageDeployment> getActiveProcessList(@Param("processList") List<String> processList,Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response
But I am getting this error now

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: ( near line 1, column 140 [SELECT pd FROM com.nividous.rpa.domain.PackageDeployment pd WHERE pd.isActiveVersion = TRUE AND pd.packageName != :packageName AND (IsEmpty(:processList) or  pd.processName in (:processList) )]